# previous layer feature does not hide or remove

Tags: javascript, openlayers

i have problem when i select one feature of the layer is display indvidually on map but when i select another feature of the same layer previous does not hide i used feature.setstyle(null) but it does not work i cannot understand what i am doing wrong

```js
         $('#prov_divsn').on('change', function() {
        // map.removeLayer(test_layer);
           //extent_pro.setStyle(null);
          
            selected = $('#prov_divsn').val();
            zone_value = $('#prov_divsn :selected').text();
            // $('#prov_divsn1').html("");
            //vector.features[selected].style = { fillColor: "green"}; map.layers[1].redraw();
          extent_pro = vector.getSource().getFeatures()[selected];
             
        extent_pro.setStyle(myStyle);
        
                      
             var poly = extent_pro.getGeometry().getExtent();
             
              
             var center=ol.extent.getCenter(poly); 
            
    
        
             map.setView( new ol.View({
    projection: 'EPSG:4326',//or any projection you are using
    center: [center[0] , center[1]],//zoom to the center of your feature
    zoom: 7
    /////here you define the levelof zoom
 }));
```

Comment: How are you selecting/deselecting the features?  If you have s select interaction with style that will be set when a feature is selected, and the original style restored when deselected.  Any changes you make in between would be lost.

Comment: vector.getSource().addFeatures(new ol.format.GeoJSON().readFeatures(data)); from this i m reading features and it is popultaed in dropdown then by using this extent_pro = vector.getSource().getFeatures()[selected]; i am getting my selected feature but when i select next feature from dropdrop of this vectorlayer first feature still display on map

Comment: When a feature style is null or undefined the layer style is used.  The alternative is to set an empty array or void function `.setStyle([])` or `setStyle(() => {})`.

Comment: i have tried to setstyle null of parent layer then child object that is extent_pro but this problem did not solve

Comment: That is expected.  Set an empty array or void function instead of null.

Comment: no didnot work still previous feature is showing

Comment: @Mike is there any other solution for this problem

Comment: setting empty array did not help